# AutoFS mount multiple CIFS Shares to same directory

Tags: linux, linux-networking, autofs

As long as I had only one mount everything was fine.

file: **/etc/auto.master**
`/mnt /etc/auto.srv1_share1`
file: **/etc/auto.srv1_share1**
`sh1 -fstype=cifs,rw,user=jdoe,domain=srv1,noexec,password=xxx ://srv1/share1`

which resulted in `//srv1/share1` mounted to `/mnt/sh1`.

But so far I've been unable to mount multiple shares. The result should be something like that:
`//srv1/share1` to `/mnt/srv1_share1`
`//srv1/share2` to `/mnt/srv1_share2`
or
`//srv1/share1` to `/mnt/srv1/share1`
`//srv1/share2` to `/mnt/srv1/share2`

After trying, googling and reading(tfm) for hours, I need your help.

My current solution/workaround is this:

file: **/etc/auto.master**
`/mnt/srv1_share1 /etc/auto.srv1_share1`
`/mnt/srv1_share2 /etc/auto.srv1_share2`
file: **/etc/auto.srv1_share1**
`share -fstype=cifs,rw,user=jdoe,domain=srv1,noexec,password=xxx ://srv1/share1`
file: **/etc/auto.srv1_share2**
`share -fstype=cifs,rw,user=jdoe,domain=srv1,noexec,password=xxx ://srv1/share2`

resulting in these mounts:
`//srv1/share1` to `/mnt/srv1_share1/share`
`//srv1/share2` to `/mnt/srv1_share2/share`

Altough I can access all files I still want to get rid of those extra `share`-directories.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the informations from this link: [Ubuntu community, Autofs, 3.1.1. Direct and Indirect Maps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs)
"Direct maps create a mount-point at the path specified in the relevant map file. The mount-point entry in `auto.master` is always `/-`"

Let's create our mount-points, and add lines to `/etc/auto.master`

```
/-        /etc/auto.srv1_share1
/-        /etc/auto.srv1_share2
```

Created mount-points will be specified at the place in `auto.srv1_share1` and `auto.srv1_share2` files.
Edit your files and add full /path/to/folder and it will work.

For example, `/etc/auto.srv1_share1` should look like this line:

```
/path/to/share -fstype=cifs,rw,user=jdoe,domain=srv1,noexec,password=xxx ://srv1/share1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

file: **/etc/auto.master**

`/mnt /etc/auto.srv1`

file: **/etc/auto.srv1**

`srv1_share1 -fstype=cifs,rw,user=jdoe,domain=srv1,noexec,password=xxx ://srv1/share1
srv1_share2 -fstype=cifs,rw,user=jdoe,domain=srv1,noexec,password=xxx ://srv1/share2`

Comment: Altough AutoFS creates the subdirectories I can't access them:  

`root@srv1:/mnt# ll`  
`total 4  
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 May 12 17:09 ./  
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 May  6 06:42 ../  
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 12 17:09 share1/  
dr-xr-xr-x  2 root root    0 May 12 17:09 share2/  
  
root@srv1:/mnt# cd share1  
-bash: cd: share1: No such file or directory  
  
root@srv1:/mnt# ls share1  
ls: cannot open directory share1: No such file or directory`

cannot open directory share1: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like some leftover cruft... it should have created /mnt/srv1_share1 and /mnt/srv1_share2 -- not /mnt/share[1,2]